# SQLalchemy + Postgres "autoincrement=True" is not working due to duplicate primary_key error. How can I fix this?

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm editing my dB using a `models.py` through SQLalchemy to make edits in my dB.

Here is my schema, pretty straightforward, nothing too complex.

```
class Security(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'security'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    symbol = Column('symbol', String(10), unique=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column('company', String(125), nullable=False)
    exchange = Column('exchange', String(50), nullable=False)
    industry = Column('industry', String(200))
    securityName = Column('security_name', String(125), nullable=False)
    issueType = Column('issue_type', String, nullable=False)
    sector = Column('sector', String(200))
    primarySicCode = Column('primary_sic', String, nullable=False)

    
class SecurityPrice(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'security_price'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True )
    date = Column('date', Date, nullable=False)
    open = Column('open', Numeric)
    high = Column('high', Numeric)
    low = Column('low', Numeric)
    close = Column('close', Numeric)
    volume = Column('volume', BigInteger)
    adj_open = Column('adj_open', Numeric)
    adj_high = Column('adj_high', Numeric)
    adj_low = Column('adj_low', Numeric)
    adj_close = Column('adj_close', Numeric)
    adj_volume = Column('adj_volume', BigInteger)
    change = Column('change', Numeric)
    changepercent = Column('change_percent', Numeric)
    changeovertime = Column('change_over_time', Numeric, nullable=True)
    symbol = Column('symbol',String(6), ForeignKey('security.symbol'),nullable=False)
    security_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('security.id'),nullable=False)
    UniqueConstraint('date', 'security_id')
    security = relationship('Security')


class SecurityStats(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'security_stats'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    week52change = Column('week52change', Numeric)
    week52high = Column('week52high', Numeric)
    week52low = Column('week52low', Numeric)
    marketcap = Column('marketcap', BigInteger)
    employees = Column('employees', Integer)
    day200MovingAvg = Column('200moving_avg', Numeric)
    day50MovingAvg = Column('50moving_avg', Numeric)
    floats = Column('float', BigInteger)
    avg10Volume = Column('avg10volume', Numeric)
    avg30Volume = Column('avg30volume', Numeric)
    ttmEPS = Column('ttm_eps', Numeric)
    ttmDividendRate = Column('ttm_dividend_rate', Numeric, nullable=True)
    companyName = Column('companyname',String)
    sharesoutstanding = Column('sharesoutstanding', BigInteger)
    maxChangePercent = Column('max_changepercent', Numeric, nullable=True)
    year5ChangePercent = Column('year5_changepercent', Numeric , nullable=True)
    year2ChangePercent = Column('year2_changepercent', Numeric, nullable=True)
    year1ChangePercent = Column('year1_changepercent', Numeric, nullable=True)
    ytdChangePercent = Column('ytd_changepercent', Numeric, nullable=True)
    month6ChangePercent = Column('month6_changepercent', Numeric, nullable=True)
    month3ChangePercent = Column('month3_changepercent', Numeric, nullable=True)
    month1ChangePercent = Column('month1_changepercent', Numeric, nullable=True)
    day30ChangePercent = Column('day30_changepercent', Numeric, nullable=True)
    day5ChangePercent = Column('day5_changepercent', Numeric, nullable=True)
    nextDividendDate = Column('next_dividend_date', Date, nullable=True)
    dividendyield = Column('dividend_yield', Numeric, nullable=True)
    nextEarningsDate = Column('next_earnings_date', Date, nullable=True)
    exDividendDate = Column('ex_dividend_date', Date, nullable=True)
    peRatio = Column('pe_ratio', Numeric)
    beta = Column('beta', Numeric)
    date = Column('date', Date)
    symbol = Column('symbol',String(6), ForeignKey('security.symbol'), nullable=False)
    security_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('security.id'), nullable=False)
    security = relationship('Security')


class SecurityAdvancedStats(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'security_advanced_stats'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    totalcash = Column('totalcash', BigInteger)
    currentdebt = Column('currentdebt', BigInteger)
    revenue = Column('revenue', BigInteger)
    grossProfit = Column('grossprofit', BigInteger)
    totalRevenue = Column('totalrevenue', BigInteger)
    EBITDA = Column('ebitda', BigInteger)
    revenuePerShare = Column('revenuepershare', Numeric)
    revenuePerEmployee = Column('revenue_per_employee', Numeric)
    debtToEquity = Column('debt_to_equity', Numeric)
    profitMargin = Column('profitmargin', Numeric)
    enterpriseValue = Column('enterprisevalue', BigInteger)
    enterpriseValueToRevenue = Column('enterprise_value_revenue',Numeric)
    priceToSales = Column('price_to_sales', Numeric)
    priceToBook = Column('price_to_book', Numeric)
    forwardPERatio = Column('forward_pe_ratio', Numeric )
    pegRatio = Column('pegratio', Numeric)
    peHigh = Column('pehigh', Numeric)
    peLow = Column('pelow', Numeric)
    week52highDate = Column('week52high_date', Date, nullable=True )
    week52lowDate = Column('week52low_date', Date, nullable=True)
    putCallRatio = Column('put_call_ratio', Numeric)
    date = Column('date', Date)
    symbol = Column('symbol',String(6),ForeignKey('security.symbol'),nullable=False)
    security_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('security.id'),nullable=False) 
    security = relationship('Security')


class SecurityRecommendations(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'security_recs'
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    ratingBuy = Column('rating_buy', Numeric)
    ratingOverweight = Column('rating_overweight', Numeric)
    ratingHold = Column('rating_hold', Numeric)
    ratingUnderweight = Column('rating_underweight', Numeric)
    ratingSell = Column('rating_sell', Numeric)
    ratingNone = Column('rating_none', Numeric)
    ratingScaleMark = Column('rating_scale', Numeric)
    consensusStartDate = Column('consensus_start_date', Date)
    consensusEndDate = Column('consensus_end_date', Date)
    corporateActionsAppliedDate = Column('corp_actions_applied', Date)
    totalRecommendations = Column('total_recs', Integer)
    datePulled = Column('pull_date', Date)
    symbol = Column('symbol',String(6),ForeignKey('security.symbol'),nullable=False)
    security_id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey('security.id'),nullable=False)
    security = relationship('Security')
```

I'm trying to insert data to my newly built `security` table. I consider it the parent. I can't get it to work because I keep getting this error.

```
Error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "security_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(0) already exists.
CONTEXT:  COPY security, line 1
```

This is an empty table, so I don't know why I'm getting this error of duplicate primary keys. I thought `autoincrement` would automatically create unique digit's for row's that can serve as `pkeys` when set to `True`

FYI this is the make up of my `security` table in psql and I'm working with `SQLalchemy` to push schema updates, hence my `models.py` file for my dB.

This might be useful, my schema for `security` in SQL taken from PgAdmin4

```
CREATE TABLE public.security
(
    id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('security_id_seq'::regclass),
    symbol character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    company character varying(125) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    exchange character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    industry character varying(200) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    security_name character varying(125) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    issue_type character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    sector character varying(200) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    primary_sic character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT security_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT security_symbol_key UNIQUE (symbol)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.security
    OWNER to postgres;
```

UPDATE:

Edited my post to now include how I insert my data below, according to @Blue Star.

```
def copy_from_stringio(conn, df, table):
    """
    Here we are going save the dataframe in memory 
    and use copy_from() to copy it to the table
    """
    # save dataframe to an in memory buffer
    buffer = StringIO()
    df.to_csv(buffer, index_label='id', header=False)
    buffer.seek(0)
    
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.copy_from(buffer, table, sep=",", null='')
        conn.commit()
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print("Error: %s" % error)
        conn.rollback()
        cursor.close()
        return 1
    print("copy_from_stringio() done")
    cursor.close()


for x in tickers:
    try:
        copy_from_stringio(conn, info[x], 'security') #info[x] is a dictionary of dataframes.
    except KeyError:
        print(f"Missing data from: {x}")
```

This is how my data object looks like before pushing it to postgreSQL.
[image: dataframe]

Comment: Can you please share how you're attempting to insert into that table?

Comment: @BlueStar I have now updated my original post to include your edits. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to see what data is going into there! Is it possible that your dataframe has an `id` column?

Comment: @BlueStar Kindly check again please.

Comment: Maybe you just need to send the list of columns to `copy_from`? So that it doesn't try to insert into the `id` column? Similarly, you should rethink that `index_label='id'`, because you don't want to be writing to a column that's based on a sequence!

Comment: Just made you edits, couldn't seem to fix my issue. I passed the column parameter, along with editing and removing the `index_label=id`, that too did not work, infact editing the `index_label` brought me back to the original error again  `Key (id)=(1) already exists.`  Only this time a 1 instead of a zero because `index_label=1`.

Comment: I also get this error when I remove the `index_label` from copyfrom: `Error: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, symbol, companyName, exchange, industry, securityName, issueType, sector, primarySicCode).
CONTEXT:  COPY security, line 1: ",symbol,companyName,exchange,industry,securityName,issueType,sector,primarySicCode"`

Comment: Several things. First, from most recent error looks like you are copying over the header row. Two, a sequence will autoincrement after an error, so you would need to [RESTART](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altersequence.html) it to get a fresh sequence. Three, you are supplying the ids so if the `COPY` works then the last id will not match the sequence as it will not have advanced, so you will need to manually advance it. Last but not least, drop the sequence(autoincrement) for the import. As you have found it will only cause problems.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I think I'm starting to narrow down and see the issue with clarity. "Three, you are supplying the ids so if the COPY works then the last id will not match the sequence as it will not have advanced, so you will need to manually advance it. " What would be the best way to solve for this issue?

Comment: My last part of my previous comment, drop the `autoincrement/sequence`.  It is generally best practice to import data into a table that is unconstrained as possible and then transfer from there to your final table. So either create a holding table for that purpose or modify your existing table.

Comment: So I ended up switching auto increment for sequence because I want a pk that increases by 1 for each new row that I copy from. The culprit i think, is my copy function that is confusing my data frame index with an actual index due to CSV delimiter. Hence the 0.